# ld cannot find generated function

Tags: c++, templates

My code:

```cpp
#include <string>

template <typename ...KVs>
const std::string BuildJson(KVs... kvs);

template <typename ...AnotherKVs>
const std::string BuildJson(const std::string& key, const char* value, const std::string& nextkey, AnotherKVs... kvs)
{
    std::string building = "\"" + key + "\": ";
    building += (value + ',' + BuildJson(nextkey, kvs...));

    return building;
}

template <typename T, typename ...AnotherKVs>
const std::string BuildJson(const std::string& key, T value, const std::string& nextkey, AnotherKVs... kvs)
{
    std::string building = "\"" + key + "\": ";
    building += (std::to_string(value) + ',' + BuildJson(key, kvs...));

    return building;
}

template <>
const std::string BuildJson(const std::string& key, const char* value)
{
    std::string building = "\"" + key + "\": ";
    building += value;

    return building;
}

template <typename T>
const std::string BuildJson(const std::string& key, T value)
{
    std::string building = "\"" + key + "\": ";
    building += std::to_string(value);

    return building;
}

template <>
const std::string BuildJson() { return std::string(); }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    BuildJson(
        "key1", "value1",
        "key2", 10000,
        "key3", 10000.6999
    );

    return 0;
}
```

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccReTAIo.o: in function `main':
template_build_json.cpp:(.text+0x11c): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const BuildJson<char const*, char const*, char const*, int, char const*, double>(char const*, char const*, char const*, int, char const*, double)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and if put `BuildJson(const std::string& key, T value)` before `BuildJson(const std::string& key, const char* value)` g++ will say:

```
template_build_json.cpp:33:19: error: ambiguous template specialization ‘BuildJson<>’ for ‘const string BuildJson(const string&, const char*)’
   33 | const std::string BuildJson(const std::string& key, const char* value)
```

Why ld cannot find the function just generated ?

Answer (score 0):

Packs can be empty.

Instead of this:

```
template <typename ...AnotherKVs>
const std::string BuildJson(const std::string& key, const char* value, AnotherKVs... kvs)

template <typename T, typename ...AnotherKVs>
const std::string BuildJson(const std::string& key, T value, AnotherKVs... kvs)
```

Try something like this:

```
template <typename... Tail>
const std::string BuildJson(const std::string& key, const char* value, const std::string& nextKey, Tail... tail)

template <typename T, typename... Tail>
const std::string BuildJson(const std::string& key, T value, const std::string& nextKey, Tail... tail)
```

with e.g.

```
    building += (std::to_string(value) + ',' + BuildJson(nextKey, tail...));
```

This requires these "there are more parameters" cases to, indeed, have more parameters (at least one, the `nextKey` parameter).

Also consider perfect forwarding, and returning a `const` value is more or less pointless.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add it and I have updated my code. But ld still not work with `BuildJson()`

Comment: @杨澍暄-YangShuXuan I don't see that your edit addresses what I've said in this answer.

Comment: Ok, I thought you refers to my missing of `const std::string BuildJson() { return std::string(); }`. But it reports a link problem. If "there are more parameters", it should not pass compile. New code is the same error.